# Use vs 2017 configuration with vs 2019

Tags: visual-studio

Im using vs 2019 with c and quite happy about it, but for a certain project I need specifically use vs 2017, which I dont have installed, and I wouldnt want to install it because I need it for very short time. Is there a way to use vs 2017 configuration on vs 2019?

Comment: What is the configuration of Visual Studio 2017 that you want to use in Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: mostly warnings, there are much more in vs2019